# Assigning values to chars in structs - c

Tags: c, struct

I have been having trouble getting my head around allowing a user to enter words into structs.
The `struct` I am using is below

```
struct class
{
  char class_num[4];
  char *class_name;
}
```

If anyone could point me how to do this or at least point me in the right direction that wuld be great.
thanks

Comment: Have you ruled out writing in C++? That looks like an IT kind of application.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Could we please avoid discussions about which language to use when it's not part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

What is "class_num" supposed to be?

In general, you have to manage string memory explicitly. The function strdup() might help.
Consider:

```
struct class cls;
char buf[256] = {0};
puts("Name?");
fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
cls.class_name = strdup(buf); 
//you need to free "cls.class_name" after its use is over
```

This will let the user enter a string up to 255 characters, and will store (a copy of) that string in the "class_name" member of the struct instance "cls".

Comment: the struct is for a school database, so class_num is a code for a school class

Answer (score 0):

In C chars are just a type of integer, except that they can be signed or unsigned (int is signed by default). So class_num[i] is a one byte integer. There are many ways to do input, and it depends on whether it's supposed to be a string or a four byte code or whatever. As Jon watt said, you'll also have to manage memory for the other field. You might look up scanf or strtod or strtol combined with read or fread. Unless you have a more sophisticated input in place like a database.